# Restarting Docker Container after reboot

Tags: docker, apache2

I start a docker container like this:

```
docker run -ti --restart="always" --name "lizmap" -p 80:80 -d -t \
-v /home/lizmap_project:/home \
-v /home/lizmap_var:/var/www/websig/lizmap/var \
-v /home/lizmap_tmp:/tmp \
jancelin/docker-lizmap
```

which makes the GIS server works like charm.
After the first two reboots the container comes up by self as expected. After some several reboots it keeps on telling me that it is restarting and restarting and restarting.

Logs are

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

httpd (pid 7) already running
```

The workaround I do is to `docker stop lizmap` and `docker rm lizmap` and then start the container again with the code above.

Does anyone has an idea about how to avoid this workaround and make the container's restart working not only for the first two time.

The docker files come from this 
[Github](https://github.com/jancelin/docker-lizmap)

Comment: Not sure if that is this, but: here ( https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/autorestart/ ) it says that autorestart requires to set autodestroy t some value. did you do that? And that link also says "ALWAYS", not "always" (not sure if that one matters either)

Comment: Is your servername set? (as in http://askubuntu.com/a/329326/5470)

Comment: Digged somehow deeper into the problem.
Seems really to depend on the existing [PID] (https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/53).
I don't know how to solve.